# Merge data from two tables into one row

Tags: sql, join

I don't have much experience with SQL query. I tried to do this using INNER JOIN but it is resulting two rows. But I need to get one row as I defined in below.  This are tables :

**Table 1**

```
ID | GP | NAME | T1
12 | 1| AAASAS  | 23
```

**Table 2**

```
ID |GP | k1
12 | 1|  600
12 | 1| 300
```

Here both ID and GP are same fields in two tables. Table 1's primary key is ID but other table doesn't have any PK.

**Expected result**

```
ID |GP | Name | T1| K1| K1
12 | 1 | AAASAS|23|600 | 300
```

Any clue or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it always going to be 1 row in table 1 mapped to 2 rows in table 2?

Comment: what happend if you have more than 2 record in table 2?!!!

Comment: @shree.pat18 No. It is not going to be 1 row in table 1 mapped to 2 rows in other table. There may be more than two rows mapped from table 2 or sometimes are may not any rows that matched with table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 1 row in Table1 maps to only 2 rows in Table2, try this:

```
select src.id, src.gp, src.name, src.t1, tgt.k1max, tgt.k1min 
from
Table1 src
inner join
(select id, gp, max(k1) k1max, min(k1) k1min
 from Table2
 group by id, gp) tgt
on src.id = tgt.id and src.gp = tgt.gp
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JQJOD91890)

Comment: Thanks for your support. But there may be more than two rows from table 2 or sometimes there may not any. Because of that cannot use min and max. Do you have any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work in 2 seperate columns. You can use a SUM() function to get only one line, but than you would get 900 for the k1 value and not 600 and 300 in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write

```
Select table1.id, table1.gp, table1.name, table1.t1, table2.k1, table2. k112 .... from table1, table2 where table1.id=table2.id;
```

You just have to take care if the primary key from table1 is a foreign key in table2.